# Choosing two colors from palette in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, viridis

I am trying to make scatter plot in python using `viridis` palette with only two values. I really like the purple, but the yellow is bearly visible. is it possible to choose middle value (blue) and purple?

```
x_test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c_test = [0, 1, 0, 1]

plt.scatter(x = x_test, y = y_test, c = c_test,  alpha=1, cmap='viridis')
```

[image: sample plot]

and it produce two colors - yellow and purple. The first one is not visible.

Comment: add `vmax=2`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom colormap with only 2 colors:

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors


x_test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c_test = [0, 1, 0, 1]

mycmap = colors.ListedColormap(['purple', 'blue'])

plt.scatter(x = x_test, y = y_test, c = c_test,  alpha=1, cmap=mycmap, s=100)
```

**Plot:**

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you, that almost answered my question as I still wanted to get colors from `viridis` palette, but i can work it out from here